# How to redirect the stdout and stderr in rolling file with Unix redirection

Tags: java, unix

I have java application which I am running on Unix from the command prompt.
I am redirecting stdout and stderr to `console.out` and `console.err` files.
The file size is increasing because a lot of information is being logged.

I want to create a rolling file, when the file size increases above a particular size,
e.g `console1.out` should get created if `console.out` size exceeds 500KB. 
Currently I am using

```
java MyAppName > logs/Console.out 2> logs/Console.err &
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pipe the result to split like this:

`java MyAppName | split -b500k - Console.log`

This will create a new file every time you go over 500k. See the man-page for split for more details and options.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use `rotatelogs`

`nohup java MyAppName 2>&1 | rotatelogs -l Console_%Y-%m-%d.log 86400 &`

This will create a new file with today's date every day