# redirect output to rolling file

Tags: java, linux, bash, log4j

There are a lot of examples how to redirect program output to file.
I need to set maximum size of the file and roll the file (vanish old messages) or backup old file and start to log to a new one.

Is there any way to do this using OS core stuff?

My customers puzzled me to create log file *per application* and log there all std out.
The application is long running application and contains with several modules that start in distinct JVMs (these are several applications in other words) and use same log4j.properties file.
I'm using java and log4j, but log4j loggs *per package* not per application. And it is not suitable for me because two modules could have same package (logger category) but shold be directed to different files.
Application modules are started using .sh scripts.

Thanks

Comment: if you can log to a server which is running SYSLOG, you can use the log4j org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender to send all log messages to SYSLOG from all the processes. (This is standard for our applications).  In the syslog-ng.conf file you can configure syslog to send all these messages to a single file.  If that would work for you, I could give a little more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189504/how-to-redirect-the-stdout-and-stderr-in-rolling-file-with-unix-redirection) fits best for me (redirects System.err and System.out to same log file, split file by size):

```
java MyApp 2>&1 | split -b500k - out.log
```

Thanks, voted up you all ;)

Answer (score 3):

log4j doesn't log on a package basis. You can provide whatever name you like to it.

In your log4j.xml, add this:

```
<appender name="USERACTION" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/var/logs/useraction.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d%m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="UserAction" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="USERACTION" />
</logger>
```

Now instantiate your logger like so:

```
private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger("UserAction");
```

Everything logged to this logger will then go into the file useraction.log. Do you see the correlation?

The thing with naming the logger after the current class is just convenient, but in no way mandatory.

I use this a lot to differentiate log entries. Some of my classes have multiple logger instances, like one for user action, one for low-level stuff, one for service calls and so on.

Comment: Just name them differently. Like JmsSenderLoggerModule1 and JmsSenderLoggerModule2. You can even make the name a variable string, if you like.

Comment: Doesn't fit for me. For example I have *org.mycompany.communication.jms.Sender* in both modules. Even by using 'JmsSenderLogger' I will fail to dirrect output to different files because both modules use the same log4j.properties.

Comment: This is same class that is used by both modules. There is no use to create several loggers for the class. And even by creating java have no clue how to distinct that class is used by several applications. Do you propose to copypast the class for several modules?..

Comment: No, but you certainly have some kind of property / possibility to detect in which module the class is running, haven't you? Then just make the name of the logger variable, as suggest in my previous comment. Like Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(getCurrentModule().toString());

Comment: No, the anser for my question *Is there any way to do this using OS core stuff?* is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189504/how-to-redirect-the-stdout-and-stderr-in-rolling-file-with-unix-redirection. And your solution require a huge amount of code to be redesigned.

Answer (score 2):

If your application can log to `stdout`, there are a number of tools out there that can help, such as:

- [rotatelogs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html), part of Apache.  This reads from `stdin` and writes out to logfiles based on the time; it takes care of changing logfiles as necessary.  You can clean up old log files with simple tools such as `find -mtime ...`.
- [svlogd](http://smarden.org/runit/svlogd.8.html), part of `runit`.  This is similar to `rotatelogs`, but automatically takes care of deleting old files as necessary, and works more on size-limits rather than time-based rotation.
- If you run your program under a process manager such as [supervisor](http://smarden.org/runit/svlogd.8.html), the process manager can take care of logging output, rolling logfiles, and so forth.

There are a number of other similar solutions out there...and I'm sure there are a number of Java-specific ideas, too, but I'll leave that for someone else.

Answer (score 2):

You can make log4j use different files in your case, depending system properties in your logging configuration. (This appender is found in the *[log4j extras](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/index.html)* project) E.g.

```
  <appender name="R2" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <param name="FileNamePattern" value="logs/log_${appName}.log.%d" />
      <param name="ActiveFileName" value="logs/log_${appName}.log" />
    </rollingPolicy>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %c -\n  %-5p: %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

See `${appName}`: You can pass this to the vm as startup parameter using `-DappName=MyApp`.  You can set this at runtime as well using `System.setProperty(.., ..)`, but this must happen before log4j is initialized. Your launcher process decides what value the property has.

You'll have log files which look like `log_MyApp.log`.

Edit: Sorry I missed the fact you're using property files and want a size based rolling policy. In this file you can write (but the actual trick is the same):

```
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File={myApp}.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1
```

This is more complete: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html :)

Comment: Good idea to name application module and use this in log4j.properties, then it is all about creation additional filters, thanks.