# How to create Spring Boot logs in standalone project deployed on windows?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-logback

I am using following to execute spring and creating logs

```
java -jar AhMachine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar > c:\log.txt
```

but this creates a single log for lifetime.

Is there any way to split this log via commandline or spring boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java -jar AhMachine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar > c:\log.txt` will pipe the *console output* to a file

`java -jar -Dlogging-file=c:\log.txt AhMachine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` will output the internal configurated *file appenders* to a file

`java -jar -Dlogging-file=c:\log.txt -Dlogging.file.max-size=4KB AhMachine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` will output the internal configurated *file appenders* to a file will create `log.txt` files of max 4KB in size, a `.gz` file is created of the *older* files

For more complex configuration I would advise using a config-file like `spring-logback.xml`, you can easily specify the location of that file via the CLI `-Dlogging.config=c:/log/config/spring-logback.xml`

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do it date wise?

Comment: I improved my answer. I do not know what the default config is in spring-boot, it could be that they use `SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy` by default. But that may also be different depending on the version.

Answer (score 1):

Not via command line,
this can all be done inside the jar via rolling file appender:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-logging-rolling-file-appenders

If you cannot access the Jar no matter what see this comment:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53395247/3942132

I haven't tested it but there should be a rotatelogs.exe process for windows as well.